# I am trying to make a dictionary of foods that are good and bad for dogs

Tags: python

I am having a problem with having it printing out a response of each item in my list, but if I get rid of the loop responsible, I can't check a users input, for example, if they put 'almond', it will say it doesn't know, because in my list, it says 'almonds'.

That is why I do a loop through each element, so it will search for the word in the element, but the loop prints that it can't find the answer a few times (unnecessarily!) and then the answer.

I hope this is understandable, and here is my code:

```
good = ['bread','cashews','cheese','coconut']
bad = ['almonds','chocolate','cinnamon']
def check(food):
  for b,g in zip(bad,good):
    if food.lower() in g:
      print(f'Yes, dogs can eat {food}.')
      break
    elif food.lower() in b:
      print(f'No, dogs cannot eat {food}.')
      break
    else:
      print(f'{food} is not in my dictionary yet. My apologies.')

while True:
  f = str(input('What food would you like to check?: '))
  check(f)
```

Comment: zip function will zip respective number columns that are equal other column values are skipped

Comment: remove zip......

Comment: You shouldn't print `..is not in myh dictionary...` until you have gone through the complete list.  Suggestion would be to use a `for/else`.  zip is also a problem since you will only use words of to the length of the shorter list.

Comment: For loop in the question is redundant and has no purpose. Remove For loops and break statements. Also as @Black_Raven mentioned in his answer an exit point from infinite while loop is an good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to loop through the two lists seperately:

```
good = ['bread','cashews','cheese','coconut']
bad = ['almonds','chocolate','cinnamon']

def check(food):
    for g in good:
        if food.lower() in g:
            print(f'Yes, dogs can eat {food}.')
            return None
    for b in bad:
        if food.lower() in b:
            print(f'No, dogs cannot eat {food}.')
            return None
    else:
        print(f'{food} is not in my dictionary yet. My apologies.')
        return None

while True:
    f = str(input('What food would you like to check?: '))
    check(f)
```

adding the `return` statement is important so that the function stops where the condition is met, if you remove the `return` statements, it will always print the last line regardless. (you could also use `break` but i prefer `return`)

Comment: Thank you so much, bro! It definitely worked. I can't believe I didn't think of using a return statement.

Comment: It does work but a lot of code, loops etc for a simple task. @JarodL for one-liner pythonic solution you can see see my answer.

Comment: @JarodL also, if youre using `return`, you dont need to keep the last `print` inside the `else` clause, it can be outside it and you can remove the `else` clause

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `zip()` function, and you would need a `return` (instead of `break`) to end the function. Also, I suggest to add an exit condition, so that the `while` loop can be stopped.

Here's my suggestion:

```
good = ['bread','cashews','cheese','coconut']
bad = ['almonds','chocolate','cinnamon']

def check(food):
    if food.lower() in good:
        print(f'Yes, dogs can eat {food}.')
    elif food.lower() in bad:
        print(f'No, dogs cannot eat {food}.')
    else:
        print(f'{food} is not in my dictionary yet. My apologies.')
    return

while True:
    f = str(input('What food would you like to check?: '))
    if f == 'exit':
        break
    check(f)
```

Output:

```
What food would you like to check?: almond
almond is not in my dictionary yet. My apologies.
What food would you like to check?: almonds
No, dogs cannot eat almonds.
What food would you like to check?: exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You this simple pythonic approach and get rid of loop:

```
def check(food):
    if any(list(map(lambda g: food.lower() in g, (g for g in good)))):
        print(f'Yes, dogs can eat {food}.')
    elif any(list(map(lambda b: food.lower() in b, (b for b in bad)))):
        print(f'No, dogs cannot eat {food}.')
    else:
      print(f'{food} is not in my dictionary yet. My apologies.')
```

Comment: it is lesser code, but it would be difficult for beginners to understand using both the `map` function and the `lambda` function in one line, along with the `any` function